# bitwiseOR does not return correct value

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

Why is it that bitwiseOR (`|`) returns `1410065407` when it should be `== a && b` in the following case - considering that javascript `int` precision is accurate to 15 numbers?

```js
let a = 9999999999; // 10d
let b = 9999999999; // 10d
let c = a | b;
let d = b | a;

console.log({a,b,c,d});

// example 2

let a2 = 999999999; // 9d
let b2 = 999999999; // 9d
let c2 = a2 | b2;
let d2 = b2 | a2;

console.log({a2,b2,c2,d2});
```

Comment: "15 digits" only *kind of* applies to floating point calculations (even then decimal is just a broken abstraction layer on top of binary arithmetic), not integer calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] considering that javascript int precision is accurate to 15 numbers

Not numbers but 32 *bits*.

The value 9,999,999,999 is higher than full 32-bit range, i.e. 4,294,967,296 (or 2^32) so what happens is that you are "converting" (clamping) the number to 32-bits which will happen with any bit-wise op:

```js
console.log(9999999999>>0);
console.log(9999999999&0xffffffff);
console.log(9999999999<<0);
console.log(9999999999|9999999999);
// etc.
```

So what happens is that 1) the number is clamped to 32-bit range, i.e. 1,410,065,407 in this case:

```
Full range would require 34-bits:
  1001010100000010111110001111111111 -> 9,999,999,999

Actual result, max 32-bits:
  --01010100000010111110001111111111 -> 1,410,065,407
```

then 2) OR'ed together which will give the same result since both numbers gets clamped first.

In the second example the number 999,999,999 is well within the 32-bit range so it goes through with no clamping needed.